# How do I programmatically set RelayState value for Google Cloud Identity SAML 2.0 flow to redirect user to the original url

Tags: saml-2.0, google-cloud-identity

Assuming I'm understanding the usage of RelayState properly, I'm thinking of using the RelayState value to redirect users to the originally requested page after going through the login flow.

While OKTA functions as expected (I'm programmatically passing the value and get it as part of the SAML response), Google Cloud Identity only returns the value of "StartURL", static value that is part of the SAML app setup.

How can I pass the original uri value to GCI to get it back after a successful login flow? Can't seem to find any documentation detailing that use case.